# Java, Round double to two decimal (round to 0.05)

Tags: java, rounding

I would like to round a double in java. I would like it rounded like this:

- 24.04 should give 24.05
- 24.07 should give 24.05
- 24.02 = 24.00
- 24.08 = 24.10

I try to use round like this:

```
    amount = amount *10;
    amount = Math.round(amount)/10;
```

But, like you can see, it's not work.

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: If you would like to display the rounded version, you will have to display it as a string.  You can use formatting rules on a string to accomplish what you want.

Comment: And what means `like you can see it doesn't work` ? It works, but it does not display like you expect, becouse you do not format the number for output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.round(amount * 20) / 20f` is one way.

Comment: Because of internal binary representation of float this can generate not rounded values.

Comment: Indeed. Only dyadic rations can be represented precisely in Java floating point. But my feeling is that the OP is not asking about this. The number of decimal places can be set when printing. (Note that this is how Excel works). BigDecimal carries a significant performance overhead that might not even be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Please not that rounding using float can generate errors due to the internal binary representation of float (same for double). 
So an operation like `Math.round(amount * 20) / 20f` for an amount 23.01 can give as result 23.000000003 (is an example I didn't checked it, but is simple to find a problem using few tests).

Use `BigDecimal` insteads.

Comment: The problem is, it's an override method. so I can't change the double for a BigDecimal! but, thank you for the precision!

Comment: By the way, integers up to the 53rd power of two can be represented exactly in a Java double.

Comment: We don't have integers. We have amount that is a floating point number with 2 decimal values. And we have a division by 20. Also for small floating point values you can have errors. For example        System.out.println(0.1  - 0.3 - 0.4 + 0.5); prints  -0.09999999999999998 instead of -0.1

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
    double[] amounts = new double[]{24.04, 24.07, 24.02, 24.08};
    for(double d : amounts){
        double d2 = Math.round(d * 20) / 20.0;
        System.out.println(String.format("%.2f -> %.2f",d,d2));
    }
```

Result is this:

```
24,04 -> 24,05
24,07 -> 24,05
24,02 -> 24,00
24,08 -> 24,10
```

[EDIT]
As other guys suggested there might be some precision error. It most likely will never be visible if you print it as suggested in my example. But it depends what do you need the number for....